# Duda con arrays en C++

Tags: c++, array

Estoy trabajando con C++ y un maestro nos dijo en clase que no podemos decirle a un arreglo que mida lo de una variable

```
int array[i];
```

pero por ejemplo puedo crear una constante y decirle que mida lo de una variable para meter dentro del array la constante?

```
#define constante x
int array[constante];
```

O si no de que forma puedo decirle al arreglo que mida lo que el usuario me pida.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Mi pregunta era como hacer un arreglo con el tamaño definido con el usuario, pero ya me contestaron que si quiero hacer eso tengo que hacerlo con punteros, muchas gracias por responder de todos modos

Comment: Para eso siempre puedes usar los contenedores de la STL, incluyendo #include <vector>

Answer (score 3):

#### C++ tradicional.

La manera tradicional de crear un arreglo de memoria dinámica es mediante el operador `new`:

Asumiendo que la variable `tamanyo` tiene la cantidad de elementos a reservar:

```
int *arreglo = new int[tamanyo];
```

Recuerda que para borrar este arreglo deberás añadir los corchetes junto con el operador `delete`:

```
delete [] arreglo;
```

#### C++ moderno.

Pero esto no se estila en C++ moderno. Los punteros en crudo se aconseja dejar de usarlos en favor de punteros inteligentes, puedes crear un arreglo de tamaño dinámico con [`std::unique_ptr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
auto arreglo = std::make_unique<int[]>(tamanyo);
```

Este arreglo creado con `std::unique_ptr` se puede usar igual que el arreglo dinámico tradicional:

```
arreglo[0] = 0;
```

Con la ventaja que no tendrás que preocuparte de liberarlo, se liberará solo al salir del ámbito en que se defina.

Answer (score 2):

> un maestro nos dijo en clase que no podemos decirle a un arreglo que mida lo de una variable

Definir un array en base a un tamaño dado por una variable se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y, efectivamente, es una característica que no está soportada por el estándar de C++... aunque muchos compiladores saben lidiar con ella.

Uno de los motivos es que `sizeof`, función empleada para saber cuántos bytes ocupa un elemento, se evalúa en tiempo de compilación. Para que esta función pueda emplearse con arrays es necesario que el tamaño de los mismos esté definido en tiempo de compilación.

> pero por ejemplo puedo crear una constante y decirle que mida lo de una variable para meter dentro del array la constante?

Exacto. Las constantes se evalúan en tiempo de compilación, luego el tamaño del array será conocido en tiempo de compilación. Requisito satisfecho.

Lo que sí me voy a permitir es hacer un inciso en este punto. El ejemplo que propones:

```
#define constante x
int array[constante];
```

No está declarando una constante sino que se trata de una directiva del precompilador y no, no es lo mismo:

- Las constantes tienen un tipado fuerte, lo que le permite al compilador hacer mejor su trabajo. Las macros no poseen tipado alguno ya que el mismo se determina después de realizar la sustitución.
- Las constantes tienen un ámbito, mientras que una macro reemplaza **todas** las coincidencias (son muy invasivas)
- Las constantes no se pueden redefinir ni pueden modificarse, mientras que las macros se pueden redefinir cuantas veces se quiera, lo que puede afectar a la sustitución realizada.

Además, la macro definida `#define constante x` no está definiendo una constante en sí misma, sino que después de actuar el preprocesador tu código quedaría así:

```
int array[x];
```

Con lo que estarías definiendo un VLA... que como hemos visto no es algo soportado por el estándar de C++. Otra cosa es que tu código fuese el siguiente:

```
#define constante 10
int array[constante];
```

En este caso el preprocesador dejaría el código así:

```
int array[10];
```

Que sí es una instrucción válida dentro del estándar de C++.

Con constantes el ejemplo debería quedar más bien así:

```
const int constante 10;
//    ^^^ tipo!!!
int array[constante];
```

> O si no de que forma puedo decirle al arreglo que mida lo que el usuario me pida.

Lo que deberías hacer en ese caso es recurrir a la memoria dinámica o a los contenedores de la STL.

Sobre cómo gestionar la memoria dinámica te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la respuesta de [@PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113820/463).

Usar contenedores de la STL tiene la ventaja de que no es imprescindible (aunque sí recomendable) conocer de antemano el número de elementos:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int numElementos;
  std::cout << "Numero de elementos: ";
  std::cin >> numElementos;

  std::vector<int> elementos;

  // Opcional: preparamos el contenedor para almacenar el numero de elementos
  // dado por el usuario
  elementos.reserve(numElementos);

  while( numElementos-- )
  {
    int valor;
    std::cin >> valor;
    elementos.push_back(valor);
  }

  for( size_t i = 0; i < elementos.size(); i++ )
    std::cout << elementos[i] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El compilador de C++ necesita reservar el espacio adecuado para el arreglo o matriz y para ello necesita que en el momento de compilación sepa de antemano cuál es el tamaño, de ahí la constante. Una forma de evitar estructuras estáticas, es emplear estructuras de tamaño dinámico mediante un puntero a memoria para declarar tu arreglo y, después lo inicializas con *new*:

```
int n;
cout<<"Introduce el tamaño del arreglo: ";
cin>>n;
int *m = new int[n];
```

No debes olvidar que después de usar estructuras dinámicas debes liberar memoria usando el operador *delete*:

```
delete[] m;
```

Comment: En C++ el `malloc` no debe ser usado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la objeción, ¡corregido!

Comment: No olvides liberar la memoria!!!

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a mejorar en este bonito lenguaje 

Comment: @Víctor de nada... para eso estamos ;)